# How to combine the investigation of two search boxes?

Tags: excel, vba, search

I have a staff list and a UserForm to search this list with several fields.

```
Matric Apellido Nombre Avión
12     Burrow   Irving F15     
42     Nelson   Howard A10
18     Krings   Jack   F18
```

How to combine the investigation of two (or more) search boxes?

I tried the following code and I'm happy with it. 
    Option Compare Text

```
' Méthode qui se déclanche lorsqu'on écris dans le champ du prénom
Private Sub name_reservist_Change()
    ListBoxResults.Clear
    If name_reservist <> "" Then searchresults
End Sub

' Méthode qui se déclanche lorsqu'on écris dans le champ du nom de famille
Private Sub surname_reservist_Change() 'www.blog-excel.com/creer-un-champ-de-recherche-vba
    ListBoxResults.Clear
    If surname_reservist <> "" Then searchresults
End Sub

' Méthode qui aggrège les résultats des recherches
Sub searchresults()
    ListBoxResults.Clear
    For ligne = 2 To Sheets("RECAP").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row
        If Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4) Like "*" & name_reservist & "*" And Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) Like "*" & surname_reservist & "*" Then
            ListBoxResults.AddItem Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) & " " & Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Yet I'm now thinking it might not be the best solution if I have lots of search screen like in this interface

[image: photo]]

It seems that I can use the "autofilter" method, or pass the range to an array and traverse it, pass the range to a recordset and make a sql. However I have never used these methods.

It's the first time I do a search engine. If you have browser design tips I'm interested. I know that my searches are not very efficient : for instance as far as any time I add a new character to the search I loop over the whole list again.

## Update

I tried to generalize with all the ComboBoxes and TextBoxes:

```
' Méthode qui se déclenche lorsqu'on écrit dans le champ du prénom
Private Sub cboFunction_Change()
    ListBoxResults.Clear
    If cboFunction <> "" Then searchresults
End Sub

' Méthode qui se déclenche lorsqu'on écrit dans le champ du prénom
Private Sub txtNameReservist_Change()
    ' on vide la ListBox des résultats pour la mettre à jour
    ListBoxResults.Clear
    ' Si le champ n'est pas vide on lance la méthode searchresults
    If txtNameReservist <> "" Then searchresults
End Sub
...

' Méthode qui aggrège les résultats des recherches
Sub searchresults()
    ' on cherche à partir de la ligne 2 jusqu'au bout de la feuille
    For ligne = 2 To Sheets("RECAP").Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row

        ' création des conditions
        cond_function = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 2) Like "*" & cboFunction & "*"
        cond_surname = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) Like "*" & txtSurnameReservist & "*"
        cond_name = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4) Like "*" & txtNameReservist & "*"
        cond_sex = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 5) Like "*" & cboSexReservist & "*"
        cond_rank = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 6) Like "*" & cboRankReservist & "*"
        cond_txtIncorporationNumberReservist = Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 7) Like "*" & cboRankReservist & "*"   

        ...

        ' on teste si les cellules sont proches à droite ou à gauche des données écrites dans les champs de recherche
        If cond_function And cond_surname And cond_name And cond_sex Then
            ' On remplit la ListBox des résultats avec les noms et prénom des personnels
            ListBoxResults.AddItem Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 3) & " " & Sheets("RECAP").Cells(ligne, 4)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean with combine them? so If name or surname changes, add to listbox both of criterias?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns That the information in the first search field is added to the second to be more precise in the search. If I am looking for Antoine as a first name and I am looking for Smith as my last name, I want the search on the last name to be made on people who already have the first name Antoine. I do not know if it's a good browser design